# How to orderBy column if it exists (else use another column) in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Table of `articles` has two timestamp columns: `created_at` and `published_at`.

The `published_at` is only used if user wants to publish article at a later time (article is hidden if `published_at` is not null and the time haven't come yet).

I want to sort articles by timestamp (to show the most recent). The timestamp to sort by is `published_at` if it is not null, else use `created_at`.

Is there an Eloquent way to do that? I would like to use it together with other constraints, preferrably I would like to make this ordering as scope.

I am trying something like

```
public function scopeRecent($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('ifnull(published_at, created_at)');
}
```

but MySQL replies with `Unknown column 'IFNULL(published_at, created_at)'`.

Comment: Are you looking for an eloquent based solution only?

Comment: @Wistar I prefer eloquent solution because I want to use it with eloquent query. But feel free to post other solutions - I might need it if I don't find a solution in Eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it like this because `ifnull` is not handled by the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`:

```
public function scopeRecent($query)
{
    $query->orderByRaw('ifnull(published_at, created_at)');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is using Postgres, it would be like:

```
public function scopeRecent($query){
    $query->orderByRaw('COALESCE(published_at, created_at)');
}
```